# Induction or pigeonhole principle or what?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Hello I've this exercise but I am not sure how you prove it formally.

Some guy $G$ was writing book for $81$ hours in $10$ consecutive days. Show that there was $2$ consecutive days that included guy $G$ writing book for at least $17$ hours combined(from 2 days).

I think this example sucks because he could be writing for $8,1$ hours each day and what then? This should be precised that he had only written in full hours. Ok - I get it now(I get it at intuitive level), but how to show this *the math way*?.

Should I use induction, pigeonhole principle or what? Also could you tell me what is classic example of this type of exercise, so I can learn more. You see If I only knew how this problem is called I wouldn't have to write this question.

Comment: Just assume that he wrote for 17h combined, and keep going on it until you come to a contradiction.

Comment: @Kurtovic I can't assume he wrote for 17h, because that what I wan't to prove. So I should assume that he wrote for less than 17 hours and then come to contradiction, but I don't really know how to translate it into *math*.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If it wasn't the case, what is the most time he could write on the first two days? The next two days? etc.

Technically, I suppose, you could use the pigeonhole principal.

And yes, you have to assume that he is counting integer hours, not fractional. Otherwise he could write $8.1$ hours per day.

Comment: Yeah but they can collide with others so best way to proving by contradiction is that i take 16 0, and then I can just have problem with 8 days and 65 days...Eventually coming to 2 days and 17 hours. Let's say it's acceptable, but I think I've seen cleaner solutions to similar problems. That's why I am asking for classics.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "they can collide..." The pigeonhole proof has day 1 and day 2 as one pigeonhole, day 3 and day 4 as another, etc. So you have five pigeonholes with 81 pigeons, so one pigeonhole must have at least $\lceil 81/5\rceil = 17$ pigeons. @Titelitury

Comment: What I mean is that you have ${10 \choose 2}$ 'holes' technically, so to look at them as 5 you have to put 0 in the 2nd day.

Comment: So, when you spend an hour working, it can be contributed to any buck of two days? No, that doesn't make sense, and it is not the argument I am making. There are five buckets in my argument.